# How do I break from compose or pipe and return all current data?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am using a pipe for input validation for login and I would like to break and return current data if possible. Is it even possible to break and return data from a `reduce`?

My current code sample:

```
const pipe = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f, g) => (obj) => g(f(obj)))

pipe(
  (obj) => {
    console.log('fn1', obj)
    return { ...obj, ...(!!obj.name || { error: ['NAME_IS_FALSEY'] })} 
  },
  (obj) => {
    // if ((obj || {}).error ) return obj
    console.log('[fn2]', obj)
    return { 
      ...obj,
      ...(
        !!obj.password ||
    obj.error ?
      { error: [...obj.error, 'PASSWORD_IS_FALSEY'] } :
          { error: 'PASSWORD_IS_FALSEY' }
      )
    }   
  },
  (obj) => console.log('[fn3 etc...]', obj)
)({
  name: '',
  password: '',
})
```

Maybe I can wrap everything in a `new Promise` and resolve midway through the reducer?

Comment: Other than throwing an exception (or checking for your `.errror`s), no. Instead of `reduce`, use a plain loop when you want a `break` statement, or recursion. No, do not use promises, there is nothing asynchronous in here!

Comment: You're right. Throw would definitely work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a recursive pipe that breaks the call chain as soon as the current value does not meet a predicate:

```
const pipeWhile = pred => (f, ...fs) => x =>
  pred(x) && f 
    ? pipeWhile (pred) (...fs) (f(x))
    : x;
```

It might be easier to read an maintain when written as a regular `while` or `for` loop.

Here's it used with your provided example:

```js
const pipeWhile = pred => (f, ...fs) => x =>
  pred(x) && f 
    ? pipeWhile (pred) (...fs) (f(x))
    : x;
    

const noError = x => !x.hasOwnProperty("error");
const rule = (error, pred) => x => pred(x) 
  ? x : { ...x, error: [error] }

const validation = pipeWhile(noError)(
  rule("NAME_IS_FALSEY", obj => !!obj.name),
  rule("PASSWORD_IS_FALSEY", obj => !!obj.password)
);

console.log(
  validation({
    name: '',
    password: '',
  }),
  validation({
    name: 'Jane',
    password: '',
  }),
    validation({
    name: 'Jane',
    password: 'PA$$W0RD',
  })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If each step in your pipe returns a Maybe object, you can use the pipeK function from Ramda to create a Kleisli-composition based pipe, which runs until one of the steps returns a Nothing. You can get a maybe implementation from the sanctuary-maybe package.

Comment: Or rather than `Maybe`, the OP wants some kind of `Error` monad/monoid. He seems to already be using one without noticing.